# Properly getting the value of a JSON field from a JavaScript Promise object

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm making a call to a url and trying to get the data as JSON, which I've basically copied from other answers on StackOverflow. However, responseData.title has two different values in the two calls I make in the second `.then()` call below:

```
var getTitleForId = async function(id) {
    if (!id)
        return false

    let url = id + "other stuff to make a valid api call"

    let response = '(null)'

    await fetch(url)
        .then((resp) => resp.json())
        .then((responseData) => {
            console.log(responseData.title);
            response = responseData.title;
    })

    return response
}
```

In the first call, `console.log(responseData.title)`, the log shows the title field from the json response.

In the second call, `response = responseData.title` (which is later returned in the method) assigns `[object Promise]` to `response` which I assume is a Promise's `toString()`

I'm not even going to pretend JavaScript is my forte, so if I'm missing something trivial, sorry in advance.

Edit: By "second call" I mean the second time I access. If you looked at the code now, what I mean is that when I return response, which I would have assumed would be assigned `responseData.title`, it is instead assigned `[object Promise]`

Edit2: Also I realize that '(null)' will never be passed on, regardless of what happens. It's just a leftover from one of the many times I've tried to make this work.

Edit3: I added the entire body of the method

Comment: Most probably this happens because you are using `await` and `.then()` chaining together. Can you refactor the code to something like `async doSomething() { const response = await fetch(url); const responseData = 
await response.json(); console.log(responseData.title); }`

Comment: @Ricky I just tried that. Same problem

Comment: Can you try to make a complete example? Are all of the lines in your example inside the same async function?

Comment: @loganfsmyth I just added the remainder of the method

Comment: @realmature Can you wrap your async function body in a try catch and see if it throws any errors? Something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/28pwu269/).

Comment: @Ricky done, I didn't get any errors

Comment: Where is the second `console.log` that you are talking about? Notice that `response` has indeed the correct value, your problem is most likely that the `getTitleForId()` call itself returns a promise (because it's an `async` function).

Comment: Yeah someone further down explained that to me yesterday. I was not aware that an async function returns a promise regardless. There is no second console.log. I just want to assign the return value of this function to a variable in its calling function and I can't figure out how to turn the Promise<String> returned by this function into the string that it holds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did should work, So it's probably how you "call it a second time" that is causing a problem. Please explain what you are actually doing.

In the mean time this could help

Try doing this

```
var title = await fetch(url)
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(responseData => responseData.title);

console.log(title);
```

or this

```
var titlePromise = fetch(url)
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(responseData => responseData.title);

titlePromise.then(console.log)
```

or as a function (why not?)

```
var getTitle = url => fetch(url)
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(responseData => responseData.title);

getTitle(url).then(console.log)
```

Edit:
Looking at your code, I'm guessing your are just calling your `getTitleForId` function plainly without any await or promise handling. An **async** function will always return a promise; here what you get when you call that function is a object of type **Promise(string)**.

https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/10/asyncawait-the-hero-javascript-deserved.html

Comment: What do you need explained? I showed the exact code there. The two times I access `responseData.title` result in two different values. When I access `response` in my original code later on in the block, its value is `[object Promise]`. I'd be happy to elaborate more but I don't know what you need elaborated

Comment: well for example, where is your variable response declared, how do you access it a second time, basically your whole code would help understand.

Comment: I just noticed your edit. You are correct, I was just calling that method. Gonna dig into that link now

Comment: For anybody coming here after the fact, it's important to note that any function you expect to handle your async function needs to also be async (until the variable you're returning is used). That might mean that every single parent function that calls any function that calls your async function needs to be async, and of course all the async functions need to have the "await" keyword

Answer (score 1):

You are using *await*, so there's actually no need to bother with the confusing *then* syntax.

Your code could be rewritten like this:

```
const resp = await fetch(url);
const responseData = resp.json();
console.log(responseData.title);
const response = responseData.title;
console.log(response); // prints the title
```

Comment: This ended up basically with the same issue, except one of the responses was undefined instead of the value of the title

Comment: Then I think the problem is not with the client code that receives the data, but with the server code that sends it.

Comment: How would I have logged the correct response before, then? I think it's more likely that I'm just not handling the async correctly because as the method is executing, it knows what the proper value should be

Comment: @PatrickHund `.json()` returns a promise, it should also be awaited. `const responseData = await resp.json();`

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
await fetch(url)
    .then((resp) => Promise.resolve(resp.json()))
    .then((responseData) => {
        console.log(responseData.title);
        response = responseData.title;
    })
```

Comment: Just tried this. I'm getting the same responses as before

Comment: Can you clarify where and when you are logging `response`?

Comment: I'm not logging response, I'm accessing it later on. See edits above

Answer (score 0):

You have to return your response inside the first `then()` call.

```
await fetch(url)
    .then((resp) => {
        return resp.json()
     })
    .then((responseData) => {
        console.log(responseData.title);
        response = responseData.title;
    })
```

Comment: In the first case the `return` is implicit: `.then(resp => resp.json())` is the same as `.then(resp => { return resp.json() })`

Comment: Just tried this, I'm getting the same responses as before